# How to Add Video.js Via NPM to Foundation 6 Zurb Template?

Tags: npm, video.js, zurb-foundation-6

I installed it via npm using `npm install --save-dev video.js` and `bower install video.js` as listed in Step #1 on [How To Add Video.js](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html).

I added the id and classes to the video tag as listed in Step #2 but it doesn't work.

I am new to npm and sass so Im not sure what else I have to do. I dont know if by installing via npm that it automatically linked the js and sass to my project. Help is much appreciated!